# Flange installed in concrete slab

Tags: concrete, flange

[image][original flange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNVms.jpg)

Replacing original 1976 toilet and found this flange. Seems in good condition but it looks like maybe it sank as you can see a lip around the center. There are no screws it is embedded in the concrete. It’s also below the finished floor, but spacers don’t fit properly. This is ABS flange on ABS pipe. Also nuts embedded in concrete holding 1/4” floor bolts
Does it need to be removed? Is there something that will raise it up properly?

Comment: If the old toilet, with wax ring, didn't leak, why do you think this needs to be changed? Of course, we don't know why you're replacing the old toilet - may you don't like the look, maybe it did leak and you just didn't share that with us. Based on the info you've given, I see no reason to make any changes at all.

Comment: It was incredibly outdated 5gal/flush, and it was beginning to leak from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You've decided to change out the toilet for a lower water consumption model. Sounds great.

You're concerned about the placement of the flange in relation to the floor, especially since "it was beginning to leak from the bottom". Wax rings *can* leak with age, but how many years did this serve faithfully without leaking? Why is it you think you need to change the flange set up now?

If it were mine, I'd simply install a new wax ring and the new toilet and call it a day. If I was *really* concerned, I'd install an extra thick wax ring (designed to fill a taller gap) and put the toilet on that.

AFAIK, the extra thick wax rings are a fairly recent invention (as in more recent than the original in 1976, but not last year), and prior to that, plumbers might use a pair of "regular" wax rings stacked in a situation like this. That would be another option for you.